# use Waterline as Standalone (no express)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, models, waterline

Good Afternoon,

I am new with node.js and I try to develope an only command app.

For this app I need an ORM and I wish to use WATERLINE as standalone but not in express framework.

I looked at the example and I succeed to see my different collections.

```
// Our collections (i.e. models):
ontology.collections;
console.log(ontology.collections);
// Our connections (i.e. databases):
ontology.connections;
```

I am stucked after this. I can't find a way to return my models and make queries.

If someone could help me taht would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you initialized Waterline in the `ontology` variable and got the collections successfully loaded as you say, now you can access each collection loaded (with `loadCollection()`) like this:

```
ontology.collection.mycollection
```

Where `mycollection` is the `identity` defined in your model.

Then you can make queries:

```
ontology.collection.mycollection.find(...)
```